# how can we pass html element as parameter in handlebar helper to achieve show more/less functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I have a scenario to add a class name dynamically to a specific element based on a condition in helper handler. Below is the code I am using

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="mytab">
     <tbody>
          {{#each records}}
          <tr id="abc"> {{ showMore $this }}
              <td>{{formatDate this.StartDateTime }}
              </td>
          </tr>
          {{/each}}
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to pass '`<tr>`' element as a parameter to 'showMore' helper handler.

Added -- Below is my handler code :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('showMore', function(ele,options) {
    var index = options.data.index;
});
```

In the above  function i need to access html element

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far for the `showMore` helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can access the `<tr>` from within the Handlebars helper. However, one approach for dynamically adding a class to an element within a Handlebars template is to do this (note that the handler reference is *inside* the `class` attribute value of the `<tr>`).

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="mytab">
     <tbody>
          {{#each records}}
          <tr id="abc" class="{{showMore}}"> 
              <td>{{formatDate this.StartDateTime }}
              </td>
          </tr>
          {{/each}}
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Then tweak your `showMore` helper to output whatever class name is applicable for the current record. If sometimes no class name is needed, the resulting empty `class=""` shouldn't hurt anything.

Note that you don't need to pass `this` to the helper, because helpers automatically receive the current context as the `this` context of the function.

Comment: Is there any way to pass records index as a parameter to 'showMore' handler ? Here records is a json/array response.

Comment: I think if you're using a recent version of Handlebars you can pass `@index` as a parameter to the helper, but I haven't tried using that feature yet. I'm about to play around and see if that works as expected...

Comment: If I use @index, I am able to pass the index of the element but all I need is to access that element based of class name or id name in my handler function and write a condition if the index is greater than 3 I will add a hidden class to other elements. If I use 'this' in the handler the output is 'Object {attributes: Object, Subject: "Test Event", Id: "00UK000000A6a6EMAR", WhoId: "003K000000puYwaIAE", ActivityDateTime: "2014-08-01T15:00:00.000+0000"…}'.

Comment: Which other elements would you be adding a hidden class to?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help given your last comment, but anyway, here's the fiddle I put together as an example of using the index to get alternating row colors on the resulting table: http://jsfiddle.net/puhkr5qx/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify a target in a show/hide link as long as it is consistently positioned in a structure where the target is easily found.  In other words, with the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr id="a" class="row">
    <td>#1</td>
    <td><button class="showHide">Show</button></td>
    <td class="content">Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b" class="row">
    <td>#2</td>
    <td><button class="showHide">Show</button></td>
    <td class="content">Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

... you can write a listener on all showHide buttons to show or hide the content.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.showHide").on("click", function(){
      $(this).closest("tr.row").find("td.content").toggle();
      $(this).html($(this).html() == "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide");
    });
  });
</script>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ft6md5d5/